# Как выбрать данные, которых нет в таблице данных?

Tags: c#, linq

Хочу выбрать запись, которой нет в базе данных.

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context));
string objectGUID;
foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
{

 DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
 Guid _guid = new Guid((byte[])(Array)de.Properties["objectGUID"][0]);
 objectGUID = _guid.ToString();
 var test = db.ADUsers.Where(a => a.ObjectGUID != objectGUID).FirstOrDefault();

 }
```

Беру objectGUID из Active Directory это своего рода уникальный номер и хочу сравнить с objectGUID в базе данных и если в базе данных нет такого objectGUID, то записать его туда.

Делаю вот так `a.ObjectGUID == objectGUID` и в консоле все Ок, получаю весь список по совпадениям.

```
 var test = db.ADUsers.Where(a => a.ObjectGUID == objectGUID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Но логично сделать так `a.ObjectGUID != objectGUID` и получить данные, которых нет в таблице ? Но этот способ не работает. Помогите!

Answer (score 1):

так как AD не поддерживает стандартные SQL запросы, то я бы сделал так:

1. Получить список всех интересующих `objectGUID` из AD в виде `List` (для справки, objetGUID и есть уникальный идентификатор в AD, другого не предусмотрено).
2. Бежим по листу. Если `objectGUID` в `List` найден в БД - удаляем из списка.
3. Оставшееся в списке добавляем в БД.

Ну или сразу добавлять в БД по факту обнаружения отсутствия `objectGUID` в БД.

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу таким способом:

```
 var selectListFromDB = db.ADUsers.Select(a => a.ObjectGUID);
            //Забираем того, что нет в базе
 var selectDifferenceLists = guidsFromAD.Except(selectListFromDB);
 var selectUsersList = from ad in searcher.FindAll() from s in selectDifferenceLists where ad.Guid.ToString() == s.ToString() select ad;
```

У линка есть метод Except, который сравнивает два листа между собой и возвращает ,то чего нету в первой листе.